# α, β in ARIMA(0, 2, 2)

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I saw 2 types of formulas for ARIMA(0, 2, 2):

$$Ŷ_t = 2Y_{t-1} - Y_{t-2} + (α + β - 2)e_{t-1} + (1 - α)e_{t-2}$$
and
$$y_t = -θ_1e_{t-1} - θ_2e_{t-2} + e_t  \quad\quad   (with \space y_t \space being \space 2nd \space difference \space of \space  Y_t)$$

I'm comfortable with the second formula which conforms to the ARIMA(p,d,q) definition.  Is the first equivalent to second?  What are α and β in the first formula?  How is that the coefficient of $e_{t-1}$ term depends on both α and β?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent models with different parameterizations.

The first form arises when showing that an ETS(A,A,N) model (a.k.a Holt's trend method) is equivalent to an ARIMA(0,2,2) model. The $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the smoothing parameters from the ETS model. See https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima-ets.html